# proving 1/(x-a) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Using $\epsilon$ and $ \delta$, prove $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}$ is continuous at every point of $(0,a)$

What I have to prove : Let $\epsilon>0$. For any $x\in(0,a)$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $y\in (0,a)$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|= |\frac{1}{x-a} -\frac{1}{y-a}|=|x-y|\frac{1}{(x-a)(y-a)}<\epsilon$.

I have no idea how to bound $\frac{1}{(x-a)(y-a)}$.

Please help me.... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: First require that $|x-y|<\frac12(a-x)$. (Remember that $x$ is fixed.) Use this to give a lower bound on $a-y$.

Answer (score 0):

We may suppose $0 <\epsilon <(a-x)$. Take $0 <\delta <\epsilon (a-x)(a-x-\epsilon)$ with $\delta <\epsilon$ . Then use the fact that $a-y >a-x-\epsilon$ to complete the proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. Answer corrected.